# Shell Script to login to a server having key pair and passphrase

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a shell script that will login to the linux servers that have key pair and pass phrase both.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion in this scenario the use of a pass phrase for a key doesn't make sense. Because you have to put it somewhere in the script file more or less plain text. Then the pass phrase is not secure and from my perspective the whole key is compromised (more or less).

Maybe there's a way by using ssh-agent and register the keys to the agent.

Comment: do u have a command that will logon to the server with password in same line that i can use in my script

Comment: No because for such purposes i have a separate key-pair without a pass phrase. The login to the server then is also limited and restricted for the task the script is dedicated for.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring a server with both a keypair and a password **really** isn't recommended (or any configuration where one has to store a passphrase on disk, for that matter).

Having said that, [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) would probably do what you want. I assume you already know how and where to keep your keyfiles.